# invoke android Intent ACTION_CALL

Tags: android, android-intent

In fact , ACTION_CALL working in most phones can work except Xiaomi mobile,a mobile made in china.
The following codes are as same as i have seen before:

```
Intent phoneIntent = 
new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:"+"15767101271"));
phoneIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
startActivity(phoneIntent);
```

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);                                        Uri data = Uri.parse("tel:"+"4006-9469-77");
intent.setData(data);
startActivity(intent); //it's ok

Comment: what OS version of XIAOMI? if the OS is Android M, you should add permission check first.